# How to output a midi note to a midi instrument in unix?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, midi, mpich, raspberry-pi2

I am building a Raspberry Pi2 cluster (aka a bramble) with MPICH2 1.4.

I also have a Launchpad, which is a board of 64+ buttons, each of which can light up with 3 different colors. 
From what I understand, by sending a midi note to it, you can light any key up, and the color depends on the velocity of the midi note.

What I want to do, is I want to visualize how the data is passing from Pi to Pi by using the launchpad, but have no idea how to pass the midi note to the Launchpad using C only.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be forever grateful!

Thank you in advance,

-Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let somebody else do the work:

```
system("amidi -p hw:1 -S '90 12 34'");
```

Or write the MIDI bytes directly to `/dev/midiXX` (if the kernel has OSS emulation).

Or use the `snd_rawmidi_*` functions to access the device directly (see the [amidi source](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=amidi/amidi.c;hb=HEAD) for details).

Comment: Thank you, that amidi command is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you once again!